# How to change the value of all input boxes at once by looping after inputting the value in the input box in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in javascript ~ I
have a requirement, I hope I can enter some numbers in the input box A at the bottom, after pressing send ~
I can change all the values ​​in the top five input boxes to the input box A. It feels like it can be done using forEach, but I don't know how to start making changes, I hope everyone can help, thank you.

```js
let jsInput = document.querySelector('#js-input');
let jsSend = document.querySelector('#js-send');
jsSend.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(jsInput.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="123">
<input type="text" value="666">
<input type="text" value="345">
<input type="text" value="1000">


<h2>I want to change all this numbe</h2>
A <input type="text" id="js-input"><button id="js-send">send</button>
```

Comment: If you're a beginner, I suggest sticking with just [tag:javascript].  While [tag:jquery] can be very powerful and save you a *lot* of time, the number of questions on SO show there can be some confusion when mixing native DOM methods with jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding a class to your other inputs that you want to change and then use `getElementsByClassName` to get them all and change their value inside a for loop since this return an array

```js
let jsInput = document.querySelector('#js-input');
let jsSend = document.querySelector('#js-send');
jsSend.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputc');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value=jsInput.value;
  }
  
})
```

```html
<input class="inputc" type="text" value="123">
<input class="inputc" type="text" value="666">
<input class="inputc" type="text" value="345">
<input class="inputc" type="text" value="1000">


<h2>I want to change all this numbe</h2>
A <input type="text" id="js-input"><button id="js-send">send</button>
```